# Store all dependent jar files in directory

Tags: java, ruby, build, buildr

I use buildr for my build process.

My project setup:

Project A -> Project B
Project A requires ant.jar

So, I want to create an output looking the following:

```
target/a.jar
target/lib/b.jar
target/lib/ant.jar
```

So far, I only managed to create a.jar inside target/
How can I persist the dependent jar files?

Comment: I'm familiar with the mvn dependency plugin but not sure if that works for buildr or not...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can extend the package task to copy all the dependencies of Project A into `target/lib` like so,

```
ANT = 'org.apache.ant:ant:jar:1.8.1'

define 'my-project' do

  define 'A' do
    compile.with project('B'), ANT

    package.enhance do
      mkdir_p _(:target, :lib)
      compile.dependencies.each do |d|
        cp d.name, _(:target, :lib)
      end
    end
  end

  define 'B' do
    # ...
  end
end
```

Comment: works great. Is enhance the best way to extend tasks? How does this work? I do not find anything about that method in the documentation of buildr

Comment: Yes, `enhance` is standard way to extend tasks.  It comes from the Rake library, on which Buildr is based: http://rake.rubyforge.org/

And more specifically you can look at: http://rake.rubyforge.org/files/doc/rakefile_rdoc.html

When we publish the next version of Buildr (1.4.3), the website will be updated to reflect a merged version of Buildr's rdoc and Rake's rdoc so it will be easier to see inherited methods for all objects.